# Get a variable after ajax when done

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
 $('#submit_id').click(function(){
    function mark() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "request1.php",
          data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data1){
          }
        });
    }
    function other() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "request2.php",
          data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data2){
          }
        });
    }
    $.when(mark(), other()).done(function(data1, data2)
    {
        console.log(data1);
        $(".results1").html(data1);
        console.log(data2); // Result
        $(".results2").html(data2);

    });

});
```

I need to pass the returned data into a variable like:

> console: undefined

Comment: Why don't you pass the returned data into a variable within the success block.

Comment: @nubinub he don't need to, because he use `when`, the problem is that the functions don't return a promise objects.

Comment: Indeed the different solutions given in answers are quite smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work like this:

```
$.when(mark(), other()).done(function(data1, data2){
    console.log(data1);
    $(".results1").html(data1);
    console.log(data2); // Result
    $(".results2").html(data2);
});

function mark() {
   return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "request1.php",
      data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
      cache: false
   });
}

function other() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "request2.php",
      data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
      cache: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank u this work well! now the problem is on submit my page will refresh the data can return on ma result page

Answer (score 4):

You have to return promise interface from your functions as:

```
function mark() {
        return $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "request1.php",
          data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
          cache: false
        });
    }
```

And you don't need to specify success callback here (but you still could).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#submit_id').click(function(){
    function mark() {
        var res = null;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "request1.php",
          data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data1){
               res= data1;
          }
        });
        return res;
    }
    function other() {
        var res = null;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "request2.php",
          data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data2){
               res= data2;
          }
        });
        return res;
    }
    $.when(mark(), other()).done(function(data1, data2)
    {
        console.log(data1);
        $(".results1").html(data1);
        console.log(data2); // Result
        $(".results2").html(data2);

    });

});
```

Comment: You are returning undefined from both functions, ajax is async by default and anyway, this is not how ajax should work

Comment: to console i have Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined